# Capture images in native resolution from Webcam

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, directshow, image-capture

when asking Google I get a lot of information and - and that's my problem - many different ways of capturing images from an Webcam using Windows. It seems the programming interface that gives this possibility has changed very often.

So my question: when I target a modern Windows (XP, Vista, 7) - which way should I use to capture images? Is there a C/C++ example somewhere available that describes the *current* way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: A DirecShow (WDM) filter graph is the normal way of doing this. This has been the preferred method since Windows 2000 where it supersceded the Video for Windows interface.

Comment: @Deanna: thanks! So WDM and DirectShow are the same interface? Funny, I thought they are something different...

Comment: In the concept of video capture, they're the effectively seen as the same thing. WDM is the driver system, DirectShow makes full use of the updated drivers to provide its functionality.

Comment: @Elmi: DirectShow is the API. Typical video capture devices are WDM driver based, DirectShow supports them through [WDM Video Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390974%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) filter + it also supports other devices as well.

Answer (score 0):

A good library for this is something like opencv and it is written with c++ in mind.

http://opencv.org/

This is a good option if you would like to do some processing on the images that you capture. the documentation on the c++ side of this is great as well so that is also a plus.

Comment: OpenCV is a tremendous overkill for just capturing an image. Additionally it uses legacy (wrong) API to capture by default.

Comment: Currently I try to *replace* OpenCV since it has enormous problems capturing images in native resolution of the camera - they always come with 640x480 instead of what the camera is able to handle.